# Automating conversion from 4:3 to 16:9 in PowerPoint, including contents

Tags: vba, powerpoint, aspect-ratio

I'm looking to find and/or develop an automated approach for converting existing PowerPoint presentations across aspect ratios (namely from 4:3 to 16:9 format).

I've been able to find some existing approaches for changing the master layout settings; however, I have not been able to find any solutions that actually proportionally scale AND place the existing content.

The goal would be for this to take an entire existing presentation and completely replicate its contents appropriately for the different aspect ratio.

Has anyone already developed or seen this?  Any suggestions on places to start?

Comment: It's not especially complicated. PowerPoint does a good job with most placeholders, so the resizing applies only to static graphics. Loop through each shape on each slide master, layout and slide, identify those that are pictures and reset the proportions of them. On this page, look for the Resize link. It's a free add-in that does that: http://www.pptools.com/downloads.htm

Comment: Resize is not actually free, but the free demo will resize the first five slides in a presentation, so it gives you a pretty good idea of whether it'll work with your slides; put the tough ones at the beginning of the presentation and let it rip. As it happens, resizing the proportions of all the shapes is enough in some cases, but not always. Sometimes it's necessary to adjust font sizes, line spacing, text indents and all manner of other stuff. Welcome to PowerPoint. Nothing's as simple as it looks.

Comment: I have a macro that does this. The process can never fully be automated because to some extent slides need to be redesigned on an aesthetic level. The key is to set a scaleX and scaleY variable, and multiply every shape’s Top, Left, Width and Height by those variables. Then multiply all font sizes of every TextRange in every shape (incl tables and charts) by either the scaleX or scaleY values, depending on whether you’re moving to a taller/shorter/wider/narrower aspect ratio. Write a separate sub to unstretch pictures. With enough tinkering and trial-and-error, you can get pretty good results.

Comment: @egerz can you share the  macro with us

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 2010 or earlier, then PowerPoint converted all objects, text boxes, charts, to the appropriate size of the new measurements.  MS removed this automatic feature in 2013 onwards, shame as the new 'double' feature offers Maximize or Ensure Fit and both are naff compared to 2010.  Only circles had to have their widths altered or they weren't circular. At work I used to keep MS 2010 just for this, changing between 4:3 and 16:9 ratios, then working in 2016, until work removed 2010.